# Shape Drawer draws nothing in lib gdx

Tags: libgdx, game-development

Simple, the shape drawer renders nothing and its just a black screen. Why is this so overly complicated to use? I can't figure this out like it just simply doesn't render anything and why is stack overflow asking for more details? What a dumb feature. Can this stupid thing reach 220 characters yet? Why is this a thing? I need to keep writing this to ask a simple question? Not almost done yet, fix this site to make it easy for people to actually use please.

```
package com.davidclue.tanksii;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.Format;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PolygonSpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;
import com.davidclue.tanksii.input.InputHandler;

import space.earlygrey.shapedrawer.ShapeDrawer;

public class TanksII extends ApplicationAdapter {
    
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int updates = 0;
    int frames;
    
    private PolygonSpriteBatch batch;
    private ShapeDrawer drawer;
    private TextureRegion region;
    
    public static int WIDTH = 1600, HEIGHT = 900;
    public int fullWidth, fullHeight;
    public static int tileSize = 64;
    public String title = "Tanks II";
    
    public static Handler handler;
    private Level level;
    
    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
        region = new TextureRegion(new Texture(WIDTH, HEIGHT, Format.RGBA8888));
        drawer = new ShapeDrawer(batch, region);
        
        handler = new Handler();
        new Camera(0, 0);
        new InputHandler(this);
        level = new Level(this, handler);
        handler.setLevel(level);
        
        level.load("levels/default/level1.png");
    }
    private void tick() {
        handler.tick();
        Camera.tick();
    }
    @Override
    public void render() {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println("FPS: " + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
            frames = 0;
            updates = 0;
        }
        
        // render
        
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 1);
        batch.begin();
        
        level.render(drawer);
        handler.render(drawer);
        drawer.filledRectangle(10, 10, 100, 100, Color.CYAN);
        
        batch.end();
        frames++;
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Before StackOverflow began requiring a certain number of sentences in questions, the site was saturated with useless questions that would just say "What's wrong with my code" and then have a bunch of code posted. The vast majority of cases require more up-front explanation for people to be able to answer the question. People usually need to know what you know or have already tried to be able to narrow it down and figure out what solution will actually help the person asking. This question is a very rare exception to needing that info to be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Texture constructor that takes only a width and height instead of an image creates a fully black texture. So if you draw black on black, you won't see anything. You should be using a pure white texture with ShapeDrawer so it can tint it to whatever color you're trying to use. Tinting with the default shaders works by multiplying a tint color by the texture color, so the texture needs to be white to be able to accurately take on the tint color.

Also, the Texture you use for ShapeDrawer might as well be 1x1 size.

And, you must always dispose of Textures in `dispose()`, or they will leak memory.

Example:

```
private Texture shapeDrawerTexture;

@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
  
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(1, 1, Format.RGBA8888);
    pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    pixmap.fill();
    shapeDrawerTexture = new Texture(pixmap);
    pixmap.dispose();
    region = new TextureRegion(shapeDrawerTexture);

    drawer = new ShapeDrawer(batch, region);

    // ...
}

// ...

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    shapeDrawerTexture.dispose();
}
```

---

Side note: there's something very weird about your Camera and InputHandler because you call their constructors and immediately release the newly created instances to the GC.

If you're going to release on Android, be extremely careful about using static fields in any of your classes, because they can stay around between sessions of the game, leaking memory and causing invalid state.

Comment: Thank you bro, it fixed it. Bless you man.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the *projection matrix* on your `PolygonSpriteBatch`, so it does not "*view*" the area you are rendering in.

Use a `Camera` (such as the `OrthographicCamera`) to setup a view port that can be passed to the batch before calling `begin()`, that way the batch knows how to project your object correctly.

Here is a complete example that renders a single red circle, center screen:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PolygonSpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;

import space.earlygrey.shapedrawer.JoinType;
import space.earlygrey.shapedrawer.ShapeDrawer;

public class TanksII extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private PolygonSpriteBatch batch;
    private ShapeDrawer shapeDrawer;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // The TextureRegion I am using here comes from a .PNG file containing a single white pixel, but it can
        // also come from your TextureAtlas
        Texture whitePixel = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("singlewhitepixel.png"));
        TextureRegion textureRegion = new TextureRegion(whitePixel);
        batch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
        shapeDrawer = new ShapeDrawer(batch, textureRegion);
        float windowAspectRatio = (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        float worldWidth = 100.0f;

        // Create a camera that views 100 units horizontally, and however many units vertically
        // to maintain the aspect ratio of the window
        // the camera is centered on (0, 0) initially, so (0, 0) is center window
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(worldWidth, worldWidth / windowAspectRatio);
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK);
        // Setting the projection matrix on the batch so that the view of the camera is applied
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        shapeDrawer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeDrawer.circle(0, 0, 20, 2.0f, JoinType.SMOOTH);
        batch.end();
    }
}
```

The example references a **.PNG** file which is a 1x1 pixel white image.

Comment: Although the OP does need to add camera functionality, their positioning is ok without a projection matrix for now because the default projection matrix of a PolygonSpriteBatch is sized pixel perfect to the screen with 0,0 in the bottom left.

Comment: No, the camera shouldn't matter here as I try to render a simple square in the middle of the screen and it doesn't work. The other guys solution worked. Also I don't use a camera because I utilize my own implementation of a camera which is more efficient as it renders only what is visible to the camera on screen.